# Why is my ReactRedux.connect statement not working?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am writing a calculator app as a project for FreeCodeCamp. I have decided to write it using React and Redux. I've written the Redux part of the app, and I started to connect Redux to React.

When I wrote all the code to connect Redux to my React app, the rendering stopped working. I used different console.log() statements to track down where the JavaScript was choking, and I narrowed it down to the connect statement found on line 241 of the linked Codepen. If you comment out line 242, and replace line 255 with 
`ReactDOM.render(<Calculator/>, wrapper);`
the app renders. However, the same code running on FreeCodeCamp's platform appears to work.

Here is the link to my CodePen: [JavaScript Calculator](https://codepen.io/CameronBurkholder/pen/Rwbqedr).

The challenge I used on FreeCodeCamp to test my code can be found here: [FCC Challenge](https://learn.freecodecamp.org/front-end-libraries/react-and-redux/extract-local-state-into-redux)

The exact code I adapted from FCC (in order to get the editor to render my component) is below. You can see the changes I made from the Pen are only in the rendering part of the code.

```
const wrapper = document.querySelector("#wrapper");

// REDUX
const initialState = {
  operation: "",
  lastResult: "",
  operand: "",
  lastInput: "",
  display: "0"
}
const operators = ["+", "-", "*", "/"];
const ADD_DIGIT = "ADD_DIGIT";
const ADD_OPERATOR = "ADD_OPERATOR";
const ADD_DECIMAL = "ADD_DECIMAL";
const CLEAR = "CLEAR";
const EVALUATE = "EVALUATE";
const { createStore } = "Redux";

function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  let newState;
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_DIGIT:
      // Number can't begin with multiple zeros, leave state the way it is
      if (state.lastInput === "0" && action.value === "0") {
        newState = state;
      // If last operation was =, start new operation
      } else if (state.lastInput === "=") {
        let newOperation = "" + action.value;
        newState = {
          operation: "",
          lastResult: state.lastResult,
          operand: newOperation,
          lastInput: action.value,
          display: newOperation
        }
      // If previous input was an operator, add operator to operation, reset display and start adding digits
      } else if (operators.indexOf(state.lastInput) > -1) {
        let newOperation = "" + action.value;
        newState = {
          operation: state.operation += state.lastInput,
          lastResult: state.lastResult,
          operand: newOperation,
          lastInput: action.value,
          display: newOperation
        }
      // Else, add digit to the current operand and display value
      } else {
        /* Append digit to operand, add to lastInput */
        /* Add digit to display */
        newState = {
          operation: state.operation,
          lastResult: state.lastResult,
          operand: state.operand + action.value,
          lastInput: action.value,
          display: state.display + action.value
        }
      }
      break;

    case ADD_OPERATOR:
      // Operation can't begin with operator unless previous operation was =
      if (state.operation === "") {
        if (state.lastInput === action.value) {
          newState = {
            operation: state.operation,
            lastResult: state.lastResult,
            operand: state.lastResult + "" + action.value,
            lastInput: action.value,
            display: state.lastResult + "" + action.value
          }
        } else {
          newState = state;
        }
      // If 2 or more operators are entered consecutively, use the most recently entered
      } else if (operators.indexOf(state.lastInput) > -1) {
        newState = {
          operation: state.operation,
          lastResult: state.lastResult,
          operand: "",
          lastInput: action.value,
          display: action.value
        }
      // Input should be handled normally for operator
      } else {
        /* Add current operand to operation */
        /* Set valid operator to lastInput */
        /* Add operator to display */
        newState = {
          operation: state.operation + state.operand,
          lastResult: state.lastResult,
          operand: "",
          lastInput: action.value,
          display: action.value
        }
      }
      break;

    case ADD_DECIMAL:
      // If used to begin a number, prepend a 0
      if (state.operand === "") {
        let newOperation = "0" + action.value;
        newState = {
          operation: state.operation,
          lastResult: state.lastResult,
          operand: newOperation,
          lastInput: action.value,
          display: newOperation
        }
      // No two decimals in one number
      } else if (state.operand.split("").indexOf(action.value) > -1 || state.lastInput === action.value) {
        newState = state;
      } else {
        /* Append decimal to lastInput, operand */
        /* Add decimal to display */
        newState = {
          operation: state.operation,
          lastResult: state.lastResult,
          operand: state.operand + action.value,
          lastInput: action.value,
          display: state.display + action.value
        }
      }
      break;   

    case EVALUATE:
      // Operation can't end with an operator
      // If input is only one operand, return that
      // Otherwise each operator must include two operands    
      if (operators.indexOf(state.lastInput) < 0) {
        /* Evalue the result of operand (Using eval() ) */
        /* Add result to display */
        /* Store result in lastResult, clear other state props */
        let result = eval(state.operation);
        newState = {
          operation: "",
          lastResult: result,
          operand: "",
          lastInput: action.value,
          display: result
        }
      }
      break;

    case CLEAR:
      /* Clear state, input, and display */
      newState = initialState;
      break;

    default:
      newState = state;
      break;
  }

  return newState;
}

function addDigit(digit) {
  let action = {
    type: ADD_DIGIT,
    value: digit
  }
  return action;
}
function addOperator(operator) {
  let action = {
    type: ADD_OPERATOR,
    value: operator
  }
  return action;
}
function addDecimal() {
  let action = {
    type: ADD_DECIMAL,
    value: "."
  }
  return action;
}
function evaluate() {
  let action = {
    type: EVALUATE,
    value: "="
  }
  return action;
}
function clear() {
  let action = {
    type: CLEAR,
    value: ""
  }
  return action;
}

const store = Redux.createStore(reducer);



// REACT-REDUX
const mapStateToProps = function(state) {
  console.log("map state to props");
  return {
    display: state.display
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = function(dispatch) {
  console.log("map dispatch to props");
  return {
    calcAddDigit: function(digit) {
      dispatch(addDigit(digit));
    },
    calcAddOperator: function(operator) {
      dispatch(addOperator(operator));
    },
    calcAddDecimal: function() {
      dispatch(addDecimal());
    },
    calcEvaluate: function() {
      dispatch(evaluate());
    },
    calcClear: function() {
      dispatch(clear());
    }
  }
}
const Provider = ReactRedux.Provider;
const connect = ReactRedux.connect;



// REACT
class Calculator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <h1>Functioning</h1>
    )
  }
}

console.log("before connect statement - line 241");
Calculator = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Calculator);
console.log("after connect statement");

class CalculatorApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Calculator/>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

class AppWrapper extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Calculator/>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the order in which you import external scripts matters.
Put `redux` below `react` because `react-redux` requires `React` to be present in the global scope.

Correct order is:

1. react
2. react-dom
3. redux
4. react-redux

Comment: Thank you! May I ask how you figured it out?

Comment: @CameronBurkholder You can see correct order on FCC Challenge page in dev tools. Generally, chrome dev tools are invaluable in solving problems with web pages and javascript. Learning how to use them is a very good investment.